# Android In App Updates - Not able to detect the update in AppUpdateInfo

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-app-bundle, in-app-update

Some log statements are thrown when we use,

```
Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
```

```
2019-06-13 18:30:40.556 28375-28375/com.marsplay.debug I/PlayCore: UID: [10312]  PID: [28375] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(<"package name here">)
2019-06-13 18:30:40.556 28375-28584/com.marsplay.debug I/PlayCore: UID: [10312]  PID: [28375] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
2019-06-13 18:30:40.560 28375-28375/com.marsplay.debug I/PlayCore: UID: [10312]  PID: [28375] AppUpdateService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.installservice.DevTriggeredUpdateService})
2019-06-13 18:30:40.560 28375-28584/com.marsplay.debug I/PlayCore: UID: [10312]  PID: [28375] AppUpdateService : linkToDeath
2019-06-13 18:30:40.564 28375-28389/com.marsplay.debug I/PlayCore: UID: [10312]  PID: [28375] OnRequestInstallCallback : onRequestInfo
2019-06-13 18:30:40.564 28375-28584/com.marsplay.debug I/PlayCore: UID: [10312]  PID: [28375] AppUpdateService : Unbind from service.
```

I've made sure -

- My signing keys are the same as uploaded in play store, as I can sign in facebook and other auths methods + I've verified myself.
- The Google play google shows in My apps and games tab, with an UPDATE button showing up.
- Application ID is the same
- I've downloaded from the Play Google numberous times.
- I've tried in the Internal Test track and a closed beta release

EDIT: 
Also I've tried to run the app from adb install, or trying to install from google play and after that deploying aab on the play google.

Comment: the following link take you through how to check for AppUpdateInfo https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#update_readiness                                                     Please provide the complete code on appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(..........) so that I will be able to further triage off of that

Comment: @tyczj Thanks for the suggestion, that worked, form it as an answer I'll make it corrct!

Comment: adding onto @RiyasaMansil comment - a failureListener will help triage.  appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener {} or appUpdateInfoTask.addOnCompleteListener {}

Comment: same problem is here... Not showing app update dialog.. tried to force close play store app.

Comment: @user2190487 After force quiting and clearing cache, data of play store it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to force quit the play store then reopen it for it to work

Comment: Thank You a lot, @tyczj! :) You make my day, really! :). It will be almost impossible to make it work without You! :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be also that your Android distro doesn't support in app updates
I'm debugging on a phone running Android GO 
and when debugging , the following line was faiing as It's not supported on the Android system 
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo ->

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't help, but going into the current apps update screen in Google Play worked.

I assume update checks are done infrequently but you are perhaps able to "force" a real check this way (or update the cached Play response)